# What is the closed form of this integral?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Consider the Chebyshev first function $\psi(y):=\sum_{p^j \leq y} \log p$, where $p$ is a prime. Define $$F(s, k) = s\int_{1}^{\infty} \psi(x + x^k)x^{-s-1}  \mathrm{d}x$$  for $ \Re(s) >$ max $(1, k)$. For $k=0$,  $F(s, k)$ seems to be the negative of the log derivative of the Riemann zeta function plus some entire function. What about for general real $k$ ?

Comment: If k is large, then it seems to be approximately F(s+k-1/k, 0) and for k small, its approximately F(s, 0). If you differentiate with respect to k, you get some weird sum + F(s-2,k)? Just spitballing here.